# What is the two-pin polarity indicator for a PCB?

Tags: pcb-design, symbol

I inserted a two-pin header (P1) into this circuit using EasyEDA.  Does the square outline mean that is the positive pin, or is there another meaning?

[image]

Comment: Square pin is pin one, this has been asked on here before, so Elliot's link should show you what you need!

Comment: Ah perfect, Elliot's link explains it all, so I'll close this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The square pin usually means it's pin 1. The polarity is up to you. Look at the 1x3 or other headers with more pins in the library, this will make more sense.